# Silverlight ChildWindow set size according to content but then fix size

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, silverlight-5.0, caliburn.micro

I want to open a ChildWindow in Silverlight. Contents are various Views which are hosted in a ContentControl inside ChildWindow.

The childwindow opens,  it's size is according to its content. It is the desired behavior. Problem is, when the content resizes (e.g. Tab control, Grid - add/remove column) the childwindow resizes too.

Is there any way to disable childwindows automatic resize? Tried to set MaxWidth/MaxHeight and MinWidth/MinHeight. The problem is I do not know how to compute size of content.

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the content of your childwindow in an extra grid control. Use the grid's Loaded event to get the computed size of your window content and constrain your window size accordingly:

```
void ExtraGrid_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    childWindow.Width = extraGrid.ActualWidth;
    childWindow.Height = extraGrid.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: This seems to be the solution, but does not work properly when in childwindows contentcontrol is another contentcontrol (eg. a tab control with two views.)

Comment: I'm not sure about your exact control hierarchy, this works for me:
ChildWindow > Grid (extraGrid) > TabControl > TabItems

Comment: I use MVVM and Caliburn.Micro.
DialogView -> childwindow -> extragrid -> contentcontrol (1) -- 
TestView -> tabcontrol -> tabitem -> contentcontrol (2)

TestView is in contentcontrol 1, some other view in contentcontrol 2.